# i deleted my application via phone and when i try to launch it again via android studio it gives an error

Tags: android

hello guys i have deleted accidentally my app that i work on in my phone and when i came back home and tried to launch it via android studio it gives me error:

```
08/23 05:25:27: Launching app
No local changes, not deploying APK
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.andy.sunshine.app/com.example.andy.sunshine.app.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.andy.sunshine.app/com.example.andy.sunshine.app.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.andy.sunshine.app/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.andy.sunshine.app/com.example.andy.sunshine.app.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

what should i do to overcome this issue. help me please!

Comment: Go to your Phone Settings & open Application Manager. Check whether your app is present. Also check at the bottom part of that list whether it shows Greyed out. If present open & uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio thinks that there are no changes and doesn't install the new APK. A workaround is to disable the "Skip installation if APK has not changed" option in Run > Edit Configurations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
The problem is in the build / run configuration of your project. You have 
to check the "Deploy application" checkbox in the Run/Debug 
Configuration screen, under the General tab.
```

Hope its help to you.